# Find critical points using spherical coordinate

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, spherical-coordinates

again!

Let $E:=\left\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 4 \right\}$ and $f:E \to \mathbb{R}$ the function define by
$$f(x,y,z):= \frac{z}{1+x^2+y^2+z^2}.$$
How can I determine the critical points of this function?

---

I suppose I can convert this function by using the spherical coordinate,
$$f(x,y,z)=f(\rho, \varphi, \theta)=\frac{\rho\cos{\varphi}}{1+\rho^2}$$

Now, I don't know what to do. I even don't know if my convertion is alright.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't have to convert this. The partial derivatives are easy to calculate.

Comment: @JohnDouma converting is a good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conversion is right.
Now, find the critical points, evaluate its gradient in therms of $\rho, \phi, \theta.$

Comment: Can I juste calculate : $\nabla f(\rho, \varphi)$?

Comment: yes, once $\partial_zf \equiv0$.